# Can I set a price for my application submission?

Tags: application-development

When you upload your app for the showcase, can you set a price and still be entered into the competition? (I don't plan to set a price, I'm just curious.)

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 6):

The [App Showdown rules](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/rules/) page says:

> Submissions: the Participant can submit more than one app, up to a
>   maximum of 2. **Participants can charge for applications** in the Software
>   Centre, but the code must be released under an Open Source license to
>   make its review possible. Canonical employees can participate in the
>   contest as long as they are not paid to create the submission.

(*Emphasis mine.*)

Clearly, you can set a price for your application and sell it on software-center. The only condition is, it has to be open source.